# how to apply cultureInfo to label in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a MVC app.
I have amount fields in my form and I am able to put amounts in Indian decimal style 
with help of the following code.

```
@{
    var indianCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN");
    @string.Format(indianCulture, "{0:N}", item.SanctionedAmount)
}
```

Now I have a line of code where I don't use the item.

```
 <div class="span7">
   Net Payment 
 </div>
 <div class="span4" id="NetPayment" style="text-align:right;">
   <strong><label for="NetAmt2" > </label></strong>
 </div>
```

The NetAmt2 value I get from the script. 
I want to implement culture info to that label, how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way:

```
<%: Html.Label(string.Format(indianCulture, "{0:N}", item.SanctionedAmount)) %>
```